# Make filechooser work JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I create a filechooser and i want to know how read a file from it:

```
public void open(){
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.Txt)", "*.Txt");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are receiving and what output are you expecting? Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file into a String like this (Java 7+):

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select txt");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        String fileAsString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileAsString.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```